# Python pandas apply too slow Fuzzy Match

Tags: python, pandas, merge, apply, data-cleaning

```
def fuzzy_clean(i, dfr, merge_list, key):  
    for col in range(0,len(merge_list)):
        if col == 0:
            scaled_down = dfr[dfr[merge_list[col]]==i[merge_list[col]]]
        else:
            scaled_down = scaled_down[scaled_down[merge_list[col]]==i[merge_list[col]]]
    if len(scaled_down)>0:
        if i[key] in scaled_down[key].values.tolist():
            return i[key]
        else:
            return pd.to_datetime(scaled_down[key][min(abs([scaled_down[key]-i[key]])).index].values[0])
    else:
        return i[key]

df[key]=df.apply(lambda i: fuzzy_clean(i,dfr,merge_list,key), axis=1)
```

I'm trying to eventually merge together two dataframes, dfr and df. The issue I have is that I need to merge on about 9 columns, one of which being a timestamp that doesn't quite match up between the two dataframes where sometimes it is slightly lagging, sometimes leading. I wrote a function that works when using the following; however, in practice it is just too slow running through hundreds of thousands of rows.

merge_list is a list of columns that each dataframe share that match up 100%

key is a string of a column, 'timestamp', that each share, which is what doesn't match up too well

Any suggestions in speeding this up would be greatly appreciated!

```
    The data looks like the following:
    df:
       timestamp   A   B   C
    0  100         x   y   z   
    1  101         y   i   u
    2  102         r   a   e
    3  103         q   w   e

    dfr:
       timestamp   A   B   C
    0  100.01      x   y   z   
    1  100.99      y   i   u
    2  101.05      y   i   u
    3  102         r   a   e
    4  103.01      q   w   e
    5  103.20      q   w   e

    I want df to look like the following:
       timestamp   A   B   C
    0  100.01      x   y   z    
    1  100.99      y   i   u
    2  102         r   a   e
    3  103.01      q   w   e
```

Adding the final merge for reference:

```
def fuzzy_merge(df_left, df_right, on, key, how='outer'):
    df_right[key]=df_right.apply(lambda i: fuzzy_clean(i,df_left,on,key), axis=1)
    return pd.merge(df_left, df_right, on=on+[key], how=how, indicator=True).sort_values(key)
```

Comment: its hard to follow this logic without first supplying some sample data, and reworking this question so that it is a [mcve]

Comment: Updated to include some sample data

Comment: Why cant you just round the timestamp? and then merge on the 9 columns

Comment: the timestamps from dfr are important in a later program. I need to keep it down to the millisecond. Also it would conflate a couple of different entries with how quickly they appear.

Comment: right so create another column say `['timestamp2']`, and that has rounded values and you merge on that and save the decimal valuies

Comment: if I rounded it would conflate some of the data

Comment: then you would filter the data

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that I believe works. Pandas has a merge_asof that follows, still verifying possible double counting but seemed to do a decent job.

```
pd.merge_asof(left_df, right_df, on='timestamp', by=merge_list, direction='nearest')
```

Comment: you might need to left_df.sort_values('timestamp') and right_df.sort_values('timestamp')